# Execute function with vs without using the .call() method

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an object that looks like this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function(s){
        return s + ' world!';
    }
}
```

What is the difference between calling the `foo.bar()` method like:

```
var greet = foo.bar.call(foo, "Hello");
```

vs

```
var greet = foo.bar("Hello");
```

What I understand from reading [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is that the first parameter of the the call method basically sets the `this` context of the method being called. But is there a benefit to using `call` to execute `foo.bar()` method in this case?  In what cases should I consider using `call` to execute a function?

Also, when is it necessary to pass `undefined` as the first parameter to the `call` method? For example:

```
echo.call(undefined, "print me");
```

Comment: Refer [___`Function.prototype.call()`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: `Let's say we have an object that looks like this:` - then you wouldn't have an object at all as that is not valid javascript